# Git commit from python

Tags: python, git

I want to write a module in python (This is the learning project) to enhance my git experience. Is there a python module for various git commands? At least the basic ones (commit/diff/log/add)?

I saw [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) but I couldn't find the support for (new) commits; its more of a repo browsing framework than a complete GIT interface. (Or did I miss something?)

Also, if there IS a python module for all this, will that be preferable, or executing the shell commands from python code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In GitPython you [create a commit from an index object](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-index-object).

In libgit2 you [create a commit from a repository object](http://www.pygit2.org/objects.html#pygit2.Repository.create_commit).

You might also want to look at this question:

- [Python Git Module experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456269/223092)

Comment: Much thanks for the "git python experience" link. I may be able to base my decision on that.

Comment: You should bear in mind that (due to the date) those answers don't mention the libgit2 based Python bindings, which are interesting because libgit2 library is a re-entrant library for interacting with git repositories.  Also, just using the subprocess module to invoke git commands (as @Ferdinand Beyer suggests) has worked fine for me in plenty of scripts, and may be all you need.

Comment: Will checkout libgit2, and others too, myself.

Answer (score 15):

I think some python source could help beginners like me not to waste precious time on digging docs.

All commits will go to freshly created `origin master`

Here it is:

```
from git import Repo
import os

path = '/your/path/here'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

os.chdir(path)

repo = Repo.init(path).git

index = Repo.init(path).index

for x in xrange (1,10):
    fname = 'filename' + str(x)
    f.open(fname, 'wb+')
    f.write()
    f.close()
    repo.add(fname)

index.commit("initial commit")
```

Comment: This gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'`... :-(  Do I have to install one of the 10,000+ git-Python packages from PyPI?

Answer (score 10):

Git is designed to consist of "plumbing" and "porcelain".  Plumbing components form the foundation, low-level system: Managing objects, repositories, remotes, and so on.  Porcelain, on the other hand, means more user-friendly high-level tools that use the plumbing.

Historically, only the most basic/performance-critical parts (mostly plumbing) were implemented in C, the rest used shell/perl scripts.  To be more portable, more and more code was rewritten in C.

With this background, I would recommend to just use system calls to the git executable for your python wrapping.  Consider your code as part of Git's porcelain.  Compared to using a specialized library:

**PRO**

- No need to learn an API -- use the `git` commands you are familiar with
- Complete set of tools -- you can use porcelain and are not restricted to low-level functionality

**CONTRA**

- Need to parse command line output from `git` calls.
- Might be slower

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython)

Install it with:

```
pip install GitPython
```

And use it like this:

```py
from git.repo import Repo

repo = Repo('/path/to/repository')

repo.index.add(['some_file'])
repo.index.commit('commit from python')

origin = repo.remotes[0]
origin.push()
```

Learn more in the [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=commit#initializing-a-repository).