# Redirecting stdout/stderr/stdin of 'git clone'

Tags: python, git

I want to write a program which will clone remote git repository and then do bunch of other stuff. The problem is that 'git clone' asks for password. It does not work when I open pipes to stdin/out/err to 'git clone' because it runs git-remote-http underneath which prompts for password on TTY.

I would like to pass the password from my program. I am using Python and Popen from subprocess. Code below does not wotk.

```
Popen(['git', 'clone', 'https://my.git.repo/repo.git'], shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you switch to ssh, you can use `ssh-agent` to avoid the password prompt.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://username:password@host ?

Comment: I cannot switch to ssh and I don't want to use username:password syntax because it stores this url with open text password in .git/config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use challenge authentication as the commenter said, I would use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest) to automate this kind of interaction

Comment: This is exactly what I need. But there is one problem. How can I access return code of child process? Because if I do child.wait() it blocks forever because of unread output and if I do child.expect(pexpect.EOF) and then child.wait() I get exception that child process already exited.

Comment: OK. I found it. I call child.close() after child.expect(pexpect.EOF).

Answer (score 2):

You can `git clone https://foo:bar@my.git.repo/repo.git` to get the data, and `git remote set-url origin https://my.git.repo/repo.git` afterwards to clear the password. But you have an race-condition between the start of the clone, and the URL-change.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using a library, you could try using [Dulwich](https://dulwich.io/).

```py
from dulwich import porcelain
porcelain.clone("https://example.com/repo.git", username="youruser", password="yourpassword")
```

This does not seem to store username or password (I've searched for the used password within the `.git` directory and did not find anything).

### Sources

Because it was quite a hassle to find an up-to-date Git library without any obvious problems, I want to list my sources for future reference:

1. [Answer to "Python Git Module experiences? [closed]" by PTBNL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479669/6377268) from 2009 that recommends (among others) to use Dulwich
2. [Answer to "Use Git commands within Python code" by Trishayyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58983005/6377268) from 2019 that still recommends Dulwich (and PyGit)
3. [Dulwich `porcelain` documentation](https://dulwich.io/docs/tutorial/porcelain.html) about `clone` that sadly does not mention that authentication is possible at all.
4. [Answer to "dulwich - clone from remote repo authentication" by harvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714070/6377268) that mentions authentication is indeed possible with Dulwich `clone`, using the `username:password@` syntax.
5. Inspired by the last linked answer, I inspected the source code a bit further and stumbled upon the `username` and `password` parameters. I've documented this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73569853/6377268) to the "dulwich - clone from remote repo authentication" question.