# Running Git clone command in Python

Tags: python, git

I am new to both Python and Git. I am in the process of writing a Python script which needs to do the same action as done by running the below git command from my workspace on a Linux server. (i.e. /local/mnt/workspace/)

```
git clone git://git.xyz.com/platform/manifest.git -b jb_2.5
```

I tried using Fab library however module fabric.api isn't installed so I couldn't proceed.
Also,

```
import git
git.Git().clone("git://git.xyz.com/platform/manifest.git")
```

didn't work.

Any other solutions to do this ?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it get an error? If so, which line, and what's the traceback? Or does it just return but do nothing, or do the wrong thing? Or…? Meanwhile, what does "couldn't proceed" mean? Do you not know how to install fabric.api, or not want to? Why did you think you wanted it in the first place?

Comment: I think, in the git module, the Repo object will provide method to clone an existing repository. So you might want to try - git.Repo().clone(). Ref - https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/tutorial.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Git commands within Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113896/use-git-commands-within-python-code)

Answer (score 17):

You can define a git function that allows you to make calls to git.  Limiting the user to git commands is important for security purposes; otherwise asking for a git url and using other techniques could result in loss of data or other malicious attacks.

```
import subprocess

def git(*args):
    return subprocess.check_call(['git'] + list(args))

# examples
git("status")
git("clone", "git://git.xyz.com/platform/manifest.git", "-b", "jb_2.5")
```

Changing it to `subprocess.check_output` allows you to see the output git prints, instead of determining success (e.g. `git("status")` raises an exception if you're not in a git repo).

---

Side note: take a look at [PIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) which is designed to help install common packages.

Comment: You really don't want to try to define a `git` function that tries to simulate the API of the module he's trying to use.

Comment: how will it behave when issuing interactive commands (like `git commit`)?

Comment: @Throoze, git always provides a way to do something without an interactive command.  e.g. `git("commit", "-m", "my commit message")`

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Thanks for your answer, but my question is more like what happens with the control when using subprocess. How does it handle standard input and background/foreground processes? Thanks :)

Comment: Try it, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

You can either shell out (via `os.system` or `subprocess`) or use the [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show what the error was beyond "didn't work", it's hard to guess what exactly your problem was.

But I'm guessing the problem is that `import git` raised an `ImportError`, because you never installed the `git` module that you're trying to use.

If so, the exact same readme document that told you how to do `git.Git().clone("git://git.xyz.com/platform/manifest.git")` will also tell you how to install it.

But most likely, all you need is something like `pip install pygit2` or `pip install GitPython` or something like that. (You may need `sudo`, and you may need to install `pip` before you can use it, and so on, but since we know nothing about your platform or your level of knowledge, there's no way to guess exactly what you need.)

Comment: I was able to get my python script working using subprocess and Popen.