# I can't git clone from script

Tags: git

I have very strange behavior:
when run git clone from tcsh script for example:

```
git clone /my repo/ .
```

I get error: fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.

```
The directory doesn't contain ".git".
```

if I run the same command after that from terminal it is ok.

version of git 1.9.3

I create this script from python.

**I found problem. if I write "#" in line before for comment in tcsh script. Why is it ?**

Comment: Is there a real space in `/my repo/`? If so you have to put the repo URL in quotes.

Comment: Please add the verbatim command you entered to *tcsh* and “terminal” (Bash?) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.` is a relative path.
Try using a full path, it should work.

`git clone myRepo /tmp/myDir` should work better.

From: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone

> Cloning to a specific folder
>
> ```
> git clone <repo> <directory>
> ```
>
> Clone the repository located at `<repo>` into the folder called `~<directory>!` on the local machine.

Comment: What is toto ? I tried using full path but it wasn't work

Comment: git clone my_repo /tmp/ does not work?    Your script has got the exe rights? Chmod +x myScript

Comment: And also try using sh not tcsh just to check :)

Comment: I create this script from python. Maybe , this reason ?

Comment: You can either shell out (via os.system or subprocess) or use the GitPython package then. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079442/running-git-clone-command-in-python   Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472552/python-way-to-clone-a-git-repository

Comment: you don't understand me. I don't run git command from python. I create tcsh script from python with git commands

Comment: Let me just try to sum up: you're in a python env or in a python script? From this python env you create a shell (tcsh) script and from there you try to perform a git clone. I'm right?  If you try to execute your script outside of python does it work? And have you tried sh rather than tcsh?

Comment: I found problem. if I write "#" in line before for comment in tcsh script. Why is it ?

Comment: What do you mean? The shebang? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) or # at beginning of a line? The shebang describes which shell should be use to execute the command. # starting a line means comment.

Comment: # at beginning of a line

Comment: This mean it's a comment. So if your comment were not protected with #, they were executed, and that's why it did not work. But it's not related to git nor Python lol

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, can you please validate it? Thanks