# Git Commands in python

Tags: python, git

I have tried the below python code to clone the repository from Git but it is not cloning and it is returning the value as 1.

```
import subprocess
repo = input ("Repository:") 
_repo_ = f '{repo}'
print ("Choose local repository ") 
local = input ("Repository:") 
local_path = f '{local}'
cmd = " git clone (git repository link)"+_repo_+".git"
print(str(cmd)) 
return_value =subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True) 
print (Return value:" +str(return_value))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Git clone command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079442/running-git-clone-command-in-python)

Comment: I removed a typo in your code. The line `cmd =  " git clone (git repository link)"+_repo_+".git"` was missing a `+` for concatenation. Also, have you checked the outpu of the subprocess command? Use `subprocess.check_call` to get the output as pointed out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332167/15016163

Answer (score 2):

Just found this library [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

```
from git import Repo
```

Try

```
Repo.clone_from(url,repo)
```

OR

```
git.Git(PATH).clone(URL)
```

Comment: What's the error ? pip install GitPython worked fine just tested

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried with from git import Repo.. Error thrown with no module named git. So I tried to install using pip install gitpython. Unable to do it because of error : Retrying failed to establish connection

Comment: Have you check to see if you have `git` installed?

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do this

```
import subprocess

repo = input("Repository:")
cmd = "git clone {}.git".format(repo)


print(str(cmd))
return_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print("Return value:" + str(return_value))
```

Comment: Again got the return value as 1 if I pass the repo link

Comment: is the repo public ? is git asking for credentials ? do you have access to the git repo? and are you using python3 ?