# GitPython git diff for the last so many days

Tags: python, gitpython

I've been trying to implement this git syntax `git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{7 day ago}'` to this `diffs = REPO.git.diff('HEAD')` `GitPython` code for some time now without a success.

Couldn't find a helpful document.

How can I look for the `diffs` of last 7 days with `GitPython`

Note: Python version: 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `GitPython` doesn't support this command so I've used an other approach.

```
git_cmd = "git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{7 day ago}'"
kwargs = {}
kwargs['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
kwargs['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
kwargs['cwd'] = '/path/to/repo/'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(git_cmd), **kwargs)
(stdout_str, stderr_str) = proc.communicate()
return_code = proc.wait()

decoded_list = stdout_str.decode('utf-8')
```

With this way I was able to achieve what I'm looking for.

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315706/5415084