# gitpython git authentication using user and password

Tags: git, authentication, gitpython

I'm using GitPython but did not find a way to push to repo using username and password. Can anybody send me a working example or give me some pointer about how to do it? 
What I need to do is:
add a file to the repository, push it using the username and password provided.

Answer (score 20):

What worked well for me (worked with GitHub, self hosted BitBucket, most likely will work on GitLab too).

#### Pre-requisites

*Note, that despite the name, `password` here is your access token generated by GitHub and NOT your GitHub password.*

```py
from git import Repo

full_local_path = "/path/to/repo/"
username = "your-username"
password = "your-password"
remote = f"https://{username}:{password}@github.com/some-account/some-repo.git"
```

#### Clone repository

*This will store your credentials in `.git/config`, you won't need them later.*

```py
Repo.clone_from(remote, full_local_path)
```

#### Commit changes

```py
repo = Repo(full_local_path)
repo.git.add("rel/path/to/dir/with/changes/")
repo.index.commit("Some commit message")
```

#### Push changes

*As mentioned above, you don't need your credentials, since they are already stored in `.git/config`.*

```py
repo = Repo(full_local_path)
origin = repo.remote(name="origin")
origin.push()
```

Comment: I think this is no longer available since Github has disabled the password login.

Comment: @DavidHsu: See the notes in pre-requisites. It's not the password. And I can confirm, that this approach still works well (at least, until 3 hours ago, because I see automated commits in one of my repositories).

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it works well on my testing code as well. After testing, the reason I got the token/password is not allowed error is because I add quotes ("xxxxx") on my token at the URL string, and after removing it, works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to do this for Azure Devops? How to change the remote variable accordingly?

Comment: I haven't worked with Azure closely. Do they have free repositories to try out for outsiders?

Comment: @ArturBarseghyan Thanks for this. I am using this code to push some changes to git. However, I am facing an issue as in, the code runs fine. But once I do `origin.push()` it gives me `[<git.remote.PushInfo at 0x7834598459b4040>]`. But I do not see anything in the remote repo. No updates or anything. Can you please suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

This is what I used for myself for pulling

### pull.py

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import git
import os
from getpass import getpass
    
project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.environ['GIT_ASKPASS'] = os.path.join(project_dir, 'askpass.py')
os.environ['GIT_USERNAME'] = username
os.environ['GIT_PASSWORD'] = getpass()
g = git.cmd.Git('/path/to/some/local/repo')
g.pull()
```

### askpass.py (similar to this one)

This is in the same directory as `pull.py` and is not limited to Github only.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Short & sweet script for use with git clone and fetch credentials.
# Requires GIT_USERNAME and GIT_PASSWORD environment variables,
# intended to be called by Git via GIT_ASKPASS.
#
    
from sys import argv
from os import environ
    
if 'username' in argv[1].lower():
    print(environ['GIT_USERNAME'])
    exit()
    
if 'password' in argv[1].lower():
    print(environ['GIT_PASSWORD'])
    exit()
    
exit(1)
```

Comment: Please see this answer to a similar question, it seems this is not the proper way to use GitPython because "if you want to parse the output, you end up looking at the result of a 'porcelain' command, which is a bad idea": https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111508/5242366

Answer (score 0):

### Clone Private Repos Using Git Module with Username and Password

Below script uses the `git` module to perform the cloning of private repositories from GitLab using HTTPS and save them in a folder with the name provided in the CSV file.

The script uses two options `-u` or `--username` and `-p` or `--password` which can be used to provide GitLab username and password.

It will clone the repositories and save them in a folder with the name provided in the CSV file.

Below is example of CSV.
| Name | URL |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Example-Demo| github.com/example/api-repo|

Save below code in script.py

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import csv
    import argparse
    import os
    from git import Repo
    import urllib.parse
    
    # Create the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Clone private repositories')
    
    # Add the arguments
    parser.add_argument('csv_file', help='The CSV file containing the repository information')
    parser.add_argument('local_dir', help='The local directory to clone the repositories into')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', help='GitLab username')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', help='GitLab password')
    
    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # Open the CSV file
    with open(args.csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            # Extract the repository name and URL from the CSV file
            repo_name = row['Name']
            repo_url = row['URL']
            repo_url_added = f"https://"+args.username+":"+urllib.parse.quote(args.password, safe='')+"@"+repo_url
            
            # Create the local directory using the repository name
            repo_folder = os.path.join(args.local_dir, repo_name)
            if not os.path.exists(repo_folder):
                os.makedirs(repo_folder)
            
            # Clone the repository using the git python module and
            print("Clonning: "+repo_name+" From: "+repo_url)
            repo = Repo.clone_from(repo_url_added, repo_folder,env={"GIT_HTTP_USERNAME": args.username, "GIT_HTTP_PASSWORD": args.password})
```

For script execution, use the following command.

```bash
python script.py -u touhid -p password repositories.csv /path/to/local/directory
```

Comment: I used a similar aproach, however if the password or token contain a slash, it will fail. We could add the parameter `safe=''` to replace the default value `safe='/'`
It would also be better to encode the username.

Answer (score -2):

I found this working solution:

1. create a script like this: [ask_pass.py](https://github.com/codeforamerica/git-jekyll-preview/blob/master/askpass.py)
2. before to execute push assign the environment vars:

> ```
>    os.environment['GIT_ASKPASS']= <full path to your script>
>    os.environment['GIT_USERNAME'] = <committer username>
>    os.environment['GIT_PASSWORD'] = <the password>
> ```

and anything works fine.

Comment: Do we need to ask_pass.py too, if yes then how?

Comment: A working example of ask_pass.py is available in the link I posted.