# How do I use a GitHub access token with GitPython?

Tags: python, github, gitpython

I am trying to write a python script that when run, will push files to one of my GitHub repositories. I'm using the package GitPython. I want to use an access token to log in into my GitHub account (instead of entering my username and password) because I have two-factor authentication. I've created the token, but I can't figure out how to add it to my GitPython code.

Here is my code so far:

```
def push(repo_dir):
    import os
    from git import Repo

    # set working directory
    os.chdir("XXX")

    #repo_dir = 'Pantone'
    repo = Repo(repo_dir)
    file_list = [
        "index.html",
        "Data/colors.csv"
    ]
    commit_message = 'Adding new color'
    repo.index.add(file_list)
    repo.index.commit(commit_message)
    origin = repo.remote('origin')
    origin.push()
```

Comment: try to use access token on the git URL as `HTTPS_REMOTE_URL = 'https://<access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/your-project'` in your git config file.

Comment: This is answered in [gitpython git authentication using user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784828/gitpython-git-authentication-using-user-and-password). As it states there "_Note, that despite the name, password here is your **access token** generated by GitHub and NOT your GitHub password._"

Note: I wouldn't consider it a duplicate question, considering OP explicitly asks for authentication with access token, whilst the referred answer asks for username/password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitpython git authentication using user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784828/gitpython-git-authentication-using-user-and-password)