# Automatic commit and push to github with pexpect

Tags: python, github, pexpect

I am trying to push all the data in a folder to `Github`. If I put the following commands simply in linux shell, everything is OK, but it dots now work on `Python` script with `Pexpect`.
It seems to me that it is very-very simple and frequently used task, but I have not find any mudule for this task.
Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import pexpect
from pexpect import spawn
import os
os.chdir("/home/python/Desktop/")
subprocess.run("git add .", shell=True)
subprocess.run( '''git commit -m "update"''', shell=True)
child = pexpect.spawn('git push origin master')
child.expect('Username.+')
child.sendline('***n@mail.net')
child.expect('Password.+')
child.sendline('sdfsdfsdfsdfs')
result = str(child.before)
print(result)
```

Comment: you can add user in `.git/config` and it will not ask for user

Comment: [How do I disable password prompts when doing git push/pull?](https://superuser.com/questions/338511/how-do-i-disable-password-prompts-when-doing-git-push-pull)

Comment: it seems you can do it with module gitpython - [gitpython git authentication using user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784828/gitpython-git-authentication-using-user-and-password)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I needed to wait for `EOF`:

```py
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('git push origin master')
child.expect('Username .*')
child.sendline('<username>')
child.expect('Password .*')
child.sendline('<password>')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)   
child.close()
```