# Print bash script output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, github

I have a Python code that will run a script file.The script file will output the version tag of specific git repository.

My script file named 'start.sh' is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git clone https://xxxxxxxxxx:x-oauth-basic@github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxx.git
cd xxxxxxxx
git config --global user.email "xxxxxxxx"
git config --global user.name "xxxxxxxxx"
IMAGE_TAG=`echo \`git describe --tags\``
echo $IMAGE_TAG
```

My Python code is as follows:

```py
import os
git_tag = os.popen('sh start.sh')
print(git_tag)
```

When I run the script file separately, it will return me the git tag. But, Whenever I try to print it in the Python code, it's not working.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should use `subprocess` instead see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string).

Comment: What's with the nested [useless `echo`s?](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python anyway, you could think of using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as an alternative. You can list all your tags with:

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo("path/to/repo")
print(repo.tags)
```

Comment: I have private git hub repository. So, it seems like I need to add authentication mechanism with this library as well.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62796479/8505949. I haven't verified it myself but seems to be a good point to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(['sh', 'start.sh'])
print(out)
```

Comment: You should not provide Python 2 answers to questions which are explicitly tagged [tag:python-3.x].

Answer (score 0):

According to [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), os.popen() function has been deprecated since version 2.6. You might want to use `subprocess` module.

P.S: I wanted to comment but couldn't hence this answer.

Comment: You are linking to Python 2 documentation. It was reinstated sometime in Python 3.x, though now it's simply an (unnecessary) wrapper for `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

For `python3-X`:

```
from subprocess
git_tag = subprocess.run(['sh', 'start.sh'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(git_tag.stdout)
```