# Set credentials to pull from local git repository with PythonGit

Tags: python, git, gitpython, git-authentication

I have a git repository on an internal server and now want to have a scheduled task that automatically pulls changes to my local version. Found the [GitPython package](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), which seems to be exactly what I need, but can't get it to work due to the password protection of the repo.

I have already cloned the repo to my local path (`git clone git@LOCAL_IP:/repo/MY_GIT.git .`) and will get prompted for the password every time I execute `git pull` from the command line (fair enough). According to [How can I call 'git pull' from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315573/how-can-i-call-git-pull-from-within-python), I then tried exactly this

```
import git
g = git.cmd.Git(MY_LOCAL_PATH)
g.pull()
```

and (of course) get an error:

```
...
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git pull
  stderr: 'Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
...
```

Unfortunately, from the many answers around the web dealing with PythoGit, I found none that tells me how I can set the password (I know that you should never ever hardcode passwords, but still...).

Comment: Local (on the filesystem, even if it's networked) or remote (i.e. via network)? `MY_LOCAL_PATH` and `LOCAL_IP` isn't helping either to clarify this...

Answer (score 1):

You can save credentials within git so that every git client can access them and won't ask the user. See [How can I save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35942754/10171966) for details on how to do that.

Comment: So instead of the `--global` flag I use `--local` to store the credentials only for that repo? Like: `git config --local credential.helper store`, then `git pull` and that's it?

Comment: Yes, that should work. If you aren't asked again for your credentials when you run `git pull` on the command prompt it should also work from GitPython.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. Whatever I try, I'm getting prompted for the PW every time. But this is another question, I'll search around.