# Download Repository to local folder and overwrite existing files by using Python

Tags: python, github, pull-request, git-clone, pygithub

I have the problem that I want to update/overwrite my local folder with a Repository, but I cant find information about how I can do that with Python. When I am cloning it I have to have a empty folder which is not the case for me.

Thank in advanced!

Comment: Have you seen [Daniel Jonsson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315573/how-can-i-call-git-pull-from-within-python) about using the built in Git pull feature of the Git module?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate a folder or update it can use with `mkdir()` function.
Otherwise, if you want to delete it you can use `shutil.rmtree()` function to delete a folder with all content of in it.
more ditailes [here](https://pynative.com/python-delete-files-and-directories/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I was able to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, `os module` is all you need! The steps are below:

1. To clone the repository:

   ```
    import os
    github_repository_url = 'https://github.com/<user_name>/<repository_name>.git'
    os.system(f'git clone {github_repository_url}')
   ```
2. Move to the directory:

   ```
    os.system(f'cd <repository_name>')
   ```
3. Take a pull i.e., update the repository:

   ```
    os.system('git pull')
   ```

Replace the placeholders `<...>` where necessary.

Comment: Thanks alot now I managed to solve the problem