# How to run multiple Linux commands in Python file

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, python-3.6

I use these three Linux commands one after each other in terminal to enable monitoring mode on Raspberry Pi 3.

```py
iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor

ifconfig mon0 up

airudump-ng -w mon0
```

I want to run this these commands in Python file instead of on terminal.

I have little idea about subprocess module but don't know how to do this.

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The code is either

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["iw", "phy", "phy0", "interface", "add", "mon0", "type", "monitor"])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", "mon0", "up"])
subprocess.call(["airodump-ng", "-w", "mon0"])
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["iw", "phy", "phy0", "interface", "add", "mon0", "type", "monitor"])
subprocess.run(["ifconfig", "mon0", "up"])
subprocess.run(["airodump-ng", "-w", "mon0"])
```

The latter is suggested [by the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) if you want to use the standard output/error.

See also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40697622/6110285).

Next time, maybe check if a [similar answer already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/6110285).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the commands as a list to `subprocess.Popen`

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["iw", "phy", "phy0", "interface", "add", "mon0", "type", "monitor"])

subprocess.Popen(["ifconfig", "mon0", "up"])

subprocess.Popen(["airudump-ng", "-w", "mon0"])
```

If you need to wait for the command to finish use `.wait` or use `subprocess.call`

Edit: If you need to read the stdout, stderr and exit status, you could pipe them to subprocess.

```py
p = subprocess.Popen([some cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
exit_status = p.wait()
```

Comment: how to print result from this code?

Comment: pipe them to subprocess. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Create and edit a script file using vi editor on the terminal. Once the editor opens to edit type in the following commands as you require.

> vi script.sh

```
iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor

ifconfig mon0 up

airudump-ng -w mon0
```

Save the file by hitting esc->w->q on your keyboard.

Now, if your script file's path is lets say, /home/user/script.sh, in the python code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sh", "/home/user/script.sh"])
```

Comment: How to do that? I am beginner to python so i dont know about it at all.

Comment: I did it but I cant find that file in root