# Can't Capture Git Command Full Output Stream

Tags: python, bash, git

When trying to capture git output stream to a file some of the output printed on the screen doesn't make it to the file.

to reproduce:

```
git show -s --oneline
```

the output on the console should be something similar to this:

> 1580ab93 (HEAD -> branch/name) some commit message

but when try to redirect the output to a file like this:

```
git show -s --oneline > file.txt
```

the output that get redirected to the file is just this:

> 1580ab93 some commit message

Can someone who knows the reason why this happens elaborate more and maybe suggest a solution or a workaround to be able to capture the full output from the command to my file.

Note: my final reach is to capture the output from a python script not just to a file.

Thanks

Comment: This works fine on my local Centos system. What environment are you running?

Comment: @RamanSailopal windows 10 (git for windows)

Comment: Interesting, I am getting the same results on Ubuntu. Output of `git show -s --oneline` is `2b202ce (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) commit message` but the content of `tmp.txt` after `git show -s --oneline > tmp.txt` is `2b202ce commit message`.

Comment: The duplicate question does seem to answer the question. I was writing up an answer when this question got marked as a dup. I found that using the `--output=<file>` option worked. For example: `git show -s --oneline --output="./tmp.txt"`

Comment: @JonnyHenly can you suggest how to use this flag to capture the command output in a python script ?

Comment: @KarimAly try using the solution in the linked duplicate question (`--decorate=short` instead of `--output=<file>`) with the answer to this SO question: [Use Git commands within Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115740/1241334)

Comment: @KarimAly So I believe the `process =`'s line would be `process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'show', '-s', '--oneline', '--decorate=short'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`, but I'm not sure and I can't test it. You shouldn't need the `branch` variable in that answer.