# dulwich - clone from remote repo authentication

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I couldn't find any resource on this topic. I need to clone from a private repository by providing the username and the password. However when they are provided as keyword arguments to 'dulwich.get-client-from-path()' an error occurs saying 'unknown argument "username"'.

This seems to be a simple thing to do, however I can't find the proper method.

Comment: have you tried using pygit?

Comment: @user12321 does it use the git binary or does it manipulate the index to carry out the tasks? The main reason I chose Dulwich was its use of the index.

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Comment: Nothing so far. I've opened an issue on Dulwich's github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
porcelain.clone("https://user:password@your_git_repo.git")
```

Comment: At the time this wasn't possible, but this has been fixed now in Dulwich. Accepting answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```py
porcelain.clone("https://example.com/repo.git", username="user", password="password")
```

I quickly checked to see if the credentials are stored locally:

- When using the `username` and `password` syntax from this answer, neither username nor password seem to be stored anywhere.
- When using the method from [harvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714070/6377268), the username is stored locally (you can check this on the command line with `git remote -v`). The password does not seem to be stored.

  - This is different from the behavior of executing `git clone https://user:password@example.com/repo.git` on the command line, which stores both username and password.

### How I found out

1. The [Dulwich `porcelain` documentation](https://dulwich.io/docs/tutorial/porcelain.html) does not mention the possibility to clone with authentication at all.
2. The [source code for `porcelain.clone`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/7173c6eee10d6541c5d55bb7e02d6d607c86f266/dulwich/porcelain.py#L400) does take `**kwargs`.

   - They are passed to [`client.get_transport_and_path`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/7173c6eee10d6541c5d55bb7e02d6d607c86f266/dulwich/client.py#L2335).
   - This passes them to [`client.get_transport_and_path_from_url`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/7173c6eee10d6541c5d55bb7e02d6d607c86f266/dulwich/client.py#L2276).
   - This passes them to [`HttpGitClient.from_parsedurl`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/7173c6eee10d6541c5d55bb7e02d6d607c86f266/dulwich/client.py#L2144). If username and password are present in the URL, they are extracted and stored into the `kwargs` dictionary (this probably is what makes harvin's answer work).
   - The `kwargs` dictionary is then passed on again somewhere. I did not check that location out, because the fact that the code knows about a `username` and a `password` key in `kwargs` was enough evidence for me to just try the snippet I posted above, and it worked.