# git status with python

Tags: python, git, module

I want to check if there are uncommited changes, or if there are unpushed commits in a git repository with python.

I could use subprocess, but a library would be better.

On pypi are several libraries with different quality. At the moment I don't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) which is full featured, very well documented and easy to use IMO. For more info, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479669/1491850)