# How to run and handle bash commands in python?

Tags: git, cmd

I have python app and want to clone git repo. I need to write "git clone", enter "username" and "password". How to do it?

```
git clone https://github.com/user/awesomerepo.git
username: login
password: password
```

upd: I want to clone private repos and because I rly need to input usr/pass :)

Comment: I would suggest you do something like [this](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to clone via the Git CLI through Python like this, you could use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (see [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)) to issue a command like:

```
git clone https://user:password@github.com/user/awesomerepo.git
```

See [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-give-username-and-password-when-do-git-clone-gitremote-git).

You are probably better off using a dedicated Git interaction library for Python, though. See [Python Git Module experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456269/python-git-module-experiences).

Comment: Oh, thank you! Didn't notice this question :(