# advantage of gitPython over executing git command with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, gitpython

I recently made a git command using python that executes git command using `subproces.Popen` so I am debating whether to take advantage of `gitPython` module or not ? Does it make any difference if `gitpython` module is used ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the subprocess module is easier to get working.  It seems to take more time to get gitPython to work.  Depending on your project, it might just be easier to use subprocess.  If you're thinking of going the subprocess route, sh is also worth checking out. http://amoffat.github.io/sh/  sh allows you to call a program as if it were a function.  Also, have you looked into https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle - it might be nice if you're just looking to automate Git commands.

ex:

```
import sh
git = sh.git.bake(_cwd='/home/me/repodir')
print git.status()
# checkout and track a remote branch
print git.checkout('-b', 'somebranch')
# add a file
print git.add('somefile')
# commit
print git.commit(m='my commit message')
# now we are one commit ahead
print git.status()
```

more info: [Python Git Module experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456269/python-git-module-experiences)

Comment: FWIW, I think this is largely the case with the historical versions, i.e. <= 0.3.2. Development has been resumed lately, and GitPython 1.0.1 is now out, which seems much better and easier than the previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

For me, GitPython has many advantages. Most important is in my opinion that the results of commands are Python objects, so you execute and receive an object with typed properties and methods. This gives you better results in face of the unexpected, like - there is no remote, the branch name is different than you think, etc.

```
repo = git.Repo('/home/user/my_project')
print(repo.branches)
```

And from the above follows for example that you can iterate over the results of commands like remotes, branches.

```
for branch in repo.branches:
    print(branch)
```

Such things get really cumbersome really quickly with raw command-line.

And, I think that GitPython has more complete support of git features than gittle, e.g. submodules support.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is a specific version of the generic question, "something that does what I want already exists, should I write it again myself from scratch?" The answer is almost always no*.

I'll also say that, for anyone who looked at GitPython when this question was written (i.e. prior to the 1.0.0 release in April 2015), you should look at it again, the project has made a lot of progress recently.

GitPython is:

- an open source, community project
- a Pythonic interface to git
- well-tested with automated unit tests
- used by hundreds or thousands of people, which means bugs are identified much quicker than with code you wrote yourself
- maintained by people who *really* understand git
- written by someone other than you, so you can focus on what you actually want to do *with* git
- very good about working with pull requests, so if there's something that's missing and you need, you're welcome to get it added
- licensed under the BSD license, so if your project is for a non-open-source-friendly company, you don't have the concerns that come with GPL or more agressive copyleft licenses

* Yes, there are some reasons why writing something yourself is necessary, whether they're legal or office politics or just [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). I'd say that all of those are edge cases.