# Git run shell command for each commit

Tags: git, shell

I would like to walk through a range of commits and perform a shell command on each.  If the command fails, I would like the walk to stop, otherwise keep going.  I have looked at `filter-branch`, but I don't want to re-write the commits, just check them out.  `for-each-ref` does not seem to allow you to specify a range to act on.

My specific problem is that I created a bunch of commits and I would like to ensure that each commit is buildable.  I would like to do something like:

```
git foreach origin/master..master 'git submodule update && make clean && make'
```

I could of course write a shell script to do this, but it seems like the sort of thing that git might have a nice way to do.

Comment: Have you considered using Python? Maybe GitPython could be a solution. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456269/python-git-module-experiences

Comment: Do you know that origin/master is good and master is bad (or the inverse), or are you just trying to test everything between them without knowing that there exists a failure at any specific place?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the latter.  I started from a working point and made a bunch of changes that worked.  Then I made several fine-grained commits from the pile of uncommitted working changes, and want to make sure that all of the in-between commits are buildable.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase with an exec option.

```
git rebase -i --exec <build command> <first sha you want to test>~
```

> --exec  Append "exec " after each line creating a commit in the final history.  will be interpreted as one or more shell
>   commands.
>
> Reordering and editing commits usually creates untested intermediate
>   steps. You may want to check that your history editing did not break
>   anything by running a test, or at least recompiling at intermediate
>   points in history by using the "exec" command (shortcut "x").
>
> The interactive rebase will stop when a command fails (i.e. exits with
>   non-0 status) to give you an opportunity to fix the problem.

Comment: The version of git I am stuck with 1.7.10 doesn't have the --exec command line option so instead I manually inserted "x make" after each pick command and it worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: You may need additionally the option `-p`&`--preserve-merges`, if the range of the rebase includes merges.

Comment: It's like HEAD~1, it says to go back one further so you actually pick up the SHA you want to test.  Standard git revision specification

Comment: As it is doing rebase SHA will change, so nice is to assign a `temp` branch to keep the old commits. Rebase on top of it we can get the addition to the old ones.

Comment: Not exactly true.  Just replaying the same commits preserves the original SHAs.  If you do anything to the commits (modification, removal, reordering) then the subsequent SHAs will change.

Answer (score 32):

You probably want [rev-list](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# test_commits.sh

while read -r rev; do
    git checkout "$rev"
    if ! git submodule update && make clean && make; then
        >&2 echo "Commit $rev failed"
        exit 1
    fi
done < <(git rev-list "$1")
```

Then you can use it with

```bash
./test_commits.sh origin/master..master
```

Comment: Needs more quotes to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion. `"$1"`, `"$rev"`, etc. Collecting all the outputs from `git rev-list` before string-splitting and iterating them also means more up-front delay than would `while read -r rev; do ...; done < <(git rev-list "$1")`, which streams in the contents as they're read rather than collecting the entire stream and parsing it up-front. (This approach is also more memory-efficient with very large revision lists, for obvious reasons).

Comment: (That said, while there's room for improvement around shell best-practices, this is absolutely the best answer here, and has my +1).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I never knew about that way of streaming in contents of a list as they are read - thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here's a cool one-liner using `xargs`.

```
git rev-list @{upstream}..HEAD | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'git checkout {} && git submodule update && make clean && make'
```

You may also want to pass the `--reverse` option to rev-list so that the last checkout is HEAD.

Comment: Depending on how far you want to go back it would be good to make a backup of `.git/logs/HEAD` before that if you don't want to have a trashed up reflog.