# How could I find lengthy commit messages?

Tags: git

I have this idea that the more keystrokes expended to decorate a commit, the more likely it is that useful thoughts are embedded in that commit. How might I find these? A commit with a single line, merely a subject, is not worth seeking out:

> ran updated format rules

Whereas a commit like this might be worth encountering:

> changed fetch of base64 images
>
> Changed the way we return base64 images when fetching for content because when we clear out the deleted image form s3 and update the content with a empty key it causes an exception trying fetch base64 images with an invalid key.
>
> This is because the actual database delete happens after we have returned response to MSC. Ideally we could move the delete to [project theseus](https://understandlegacycode.com/blog/ship-of-theseus-avoid-rewrite-legacy-system/) and then no longer do the db call on the MSC side. For now this should work.

How could I retrieve a list of such commits from the git log?

Comment: Possibly a solution using [`git rebase -i --exec` or `git rev-list`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26983700/3282436), though I bet it would take a while to run on large repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I finally broke down and [wrote a thing](https://gist.github.com/djeikyb/0405d82d1674c59edfd2cb5b15bbea7e), copied here:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

countWords() {
    commit="$1"
    word_count=$(git show --format='%B' --no-patch "$commit" | wc -w)
    auth="$(git show --format='%h %aN / %cN' --no-patch $commit)"
    echo "$word_count $auth"
    exit 0
}

[ -n "$2" ] && countWords "$2"

range="origin/master"
[ -n "$1" ] && range="origin/master~$1..origin/master" 

echo "$range"

git log --format='%H' "$range" | xargs -I{} -P 16 $0 --last "{}"
```

To get the word count of the last ten commits:

```
git wc 10
```

To get the word count of all commits:

```
git wc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list --all | git cat-file --batch-check | sort -nk3
```

or instead of the sort you could do something like

```
git rev-list --all | git cat-file --batch-check \
| awk '$3 > 300 {print $1}' | git log --no-walk --stdin
```